# Printing value of unknown variable in Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, printing

I am trying to print a statement in a Python file to better understand where I am getting an AssertionError. Here is the code:

```
    class test_rosenbrock_function(object):
       def __init__(self, dim=5):
         self.x = 0 <-- important point
         self.n = 2*dim
         self.dim = dim
         self.domain = [ (1,3) ]*self.n
         self.optimizer = differential_evolution_optimizer(self,rand_inputs,etc...)
         print 'x before for loop= ',self.x
         for x in self.x:
           print 'x in for loop test_rb: ',x
           assert abs(x-1.0)<1e-2
```

If depends on a few different classes and functions within my file that are all working fine. The problem I am having is trying to understand what happends to the self.x variable after the differential_evolution_optimizer function is called. When I look at my shell, this is what I get:

```
 --> x before for loop=  <scitbx_array_family_flex_ext.double object at 0x102b6bf70>
     x in for loop test_rb:  0.0
     Traceback (most recent call last):
       File "optimizer.py", line 270, in <module>
         run()
       File "optimizer.py", line 265, in run
         test_rosenbrock_function(1)
       File "optimizer.py", line 244, in __init__
         assert abs(x-1.0)<1e-2
     AssertionError
```

My question is how can I print the (-->) statment so I can actually read the value of self.x instead of what type and where it is located?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly that type does not define a `__str__` method to present its instances nicely.  Just do the presentation yourself, e.g, instead of `print(self.x)`, `print(list(self.x))`.

Answer (score 0):

`print` looks at an object's `__str__` method.  If the `__str__` method isn't defined, then python looks at the object's `__repr__` method.  By default, all objects have a `__repr__` method that returns something like `'<type_of_object at memory_address>'`.

If you have access to the code where the class is defined, the solution is to simply define a `__str__` method on the class that returns something more sensible.  e.g.

```
class Foo(object):
    def __str__(self):
        return 'I am a Foo'

f = Foo()
print f  # I am a Foo
```

If you don't have (easy) access to the code where the class definition is, then your best bet is to print some of the class instances' attributes.

Answer (score 0):

You have a bunch of errors in this code. Firstly an int like `self.x` (which is 0) is not iterable so the `for` loop would not work at all.

If you want to print the `self.x` attribute you can do it like this:

```
    class test_rosenbrock_function(object):
        def __init__(self, dim=5):
            self.x = 0
            self.dim = dim
            #other code here

     Rosen = test_rosenbrock_function()
     print Rosen.x   #gives 0
     print Rosen.dim  #gives 5
```